Store long kived accessTokens inside nextjs 14 and handle recurring refresh
I have a nextjs 14 web app which shows an instagram feed. To load the feed I implemented the Instagram Basic Display API.
Currently I use an external service (Google Secrets Manager) to store the long lived access token for the Instagram Basic Display API and I refresh it using a cloud function. The whole solution was suggested 2 years ago here on stack overflow: How to refresh Instagram Basic Display API token automatically?
Since nextjs can now properly separate client and server code I think there should be a way to handle the token rotation directly in nextjs.
I will not longer be able to use gcp due to some company restrictions and I also want to reduce external dependencies. This application is hosted on vercel, therefore I am currently looking into Vercel Storage solutions.
The token and the expiry of the token are the only things that need to be stored inside the storage solution.
To solve the rotation i could probably use a middleware in nextjs which checks if the expiry date of the token is near and then refresh the token accordingly.
What would be a nextjs 14 native way to solve this problem?
I am not sure which solution would be the most nextjs native way to do it and I cannot find references or solutions for this problem in the nextjs documentation.

You need to bring an external storage, as you mentioned. Postgres with encryption seems the most "default" option. The bottom line is: Next.js will support whatever solution you will need to apply. It is not a Next.js concern which type of storage, however. Next.js should be stateless, and you "plug" the state by bringing your own storage solution.

Why do you think postgres is the most default option?

Honestly? We tend to look for the next new shiny thing, and PostgreSQL is innovating as much as those newer alternatives.
https://www.amazingcto.com/postgres-for-everything/
